# Merged Documents and Downloads and can't undo it in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, window, user-folders

I'm stupid, can't read and merged Documents and Downloads into 1 folder. The warning was clear [image]

Here's hoping some tech-savvy superuser know's how to undo my mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is proposed by the respected TenForums.com: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-restore-default-location-personal-folders-windows-10-a.html

Create a batch file with the following information:

```
@echo off 

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.tenforums.com
:: Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-users-personal-folders-restore-default-location-windows-10-a.html


taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

if not exist "%UserProfile%\Downloads" mkdir "%UserProfile%\Downloads"

reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads" /f

reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%"\Downloads" /f

reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "{7D83EE9B-2244-4E70-B1F5-5393042AF1E4}" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%"\Downloads" /f

attrib +r -s -h "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" /S /D

timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

start explorer.exe
```

And run the bat file. Then move files from the old location to the new one.

Comment: Cheers! That did it! Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

This involves a registry hack. I had to do it once before.  It's not fun.

- Go to Start, type `run`, hit enter, and type `regedit`.  Then hit Enter.  This puts you into the registry editor.   Congrats, you're now in the app that can break stuff, so be careful.
- Using the presented window, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`
- You should see a list on the right with the folders and their paths. Right click on them one at a time, then Modify. The hex codes are how the computer reads them.  Correct the path.

  - My notes show the folders for Downloads are:

    1.`{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}`

    2. `{7D83EE9B-2244-4E70-B1F5-5393042AF1E4}`
  - Pictures are in:

    1. `{0DDD015D-B06C-45D5-8C4C-F59713854639}`
  - I have a note here that says `{A52BBA46-E9E1-435f-B3D9-28DAA648C0F6}` is your OneDrive folder.

Restart the PC. When it loads up, open `C:\Users\<YourUserIDHere>` and refresh the window a few times.

Alternatively, reinstall Windows.    If you can backup your stuff and a reinstall won't hurt you, I'd do that and save yourself some aspirin..

Comment: Before you reinstall you should just create a new user profile. Much less fuss.